# Creating Routes in NodeJs

Tags: node.js, routes

I am trying to build a user registration forum for a web app.

To refactor my code I created a folder named api and defined some routes in index.js (/api/routes/index.js).

Now I wanted to route my signup form to this route in (/api/routes/index.js) so that the data can go to **user_sign_up** function which is defined in (api/controllers/users.js)

my **app.js** looks like:

```
// some code
var routesApi = require('./api/routes/index');
app.use('/api', routesApi);
// some code
```

my (/api/routes/index) looks like:

```
// some code
var ctrlevents = require('../controllers/users');
router.post('/registeruser', ctrlevents.user_sign_up);
// some code
module.exports = router;
```

In server folder of my app, I have views folder under which all .html files are present.

How do I define routes for action attribute in signup form?

my **users.js** looks like:

```
module.exports.user_sign_up = (req, res) => {

// some code
};
```

I tried:

```
<form method="POST" action="/registeruser">
```

got this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lUEAC.png)

Following is working but getting 500 status.

```
<form method="POST" action="/api/registeruser">
```

Adding user_sign_up function:

```
/* GET signup data */
module.exports.user_sign_up = (req, res) => {

  Name: req.body.username;
  email: req.body.email;
  password: req.body.password;
  cpassword: req.body.cpassword;

  console.log('ghfhghgh');
  console.log(email);
  console.log(password);
  console.log(cpassword);

  req.checkBody('Name', 'Name is required').notEmpty();
  req.checkBody('email', 'Email is required').notEmpty();
  req.checkBody('password', 'Password is required').notEmpty();
  req.checkBody('cpassword', 'Passwords do not match').equals(req.body.password);

  let errors = req.validationErrors();

  if (err) {

    res.render('register', {
      errors:errors
    });
  }

  else {

    let newUser = new User({
      Name:Name,
      email:email,
      password:password
    })
  }

  bcrypt.genSalt(10, (err, salt) => {

    bcrypt.hash(newUser.password, salt, (err, hash) => {

      if(err) {

        console.log(err);
      }

      newUser.password = hash;

      newUser.save((err) => {

        if(err) {

          console.log(err);
          return;
        }

        else {
          req.flash('success', 'Welcome to TechPath');
          req.redirect('/blog');
        }

      })

    });

  })

};
```

Comment: Do you get or reaches to "Welcome to TechPath"?

Comment: no. only thing that appears on console is console.log('ghfhghgh');

Comment: Try `=` sign to assign the value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to assign value using `=` sign

```
  Name = req.body.username;
  email = req.body.email;
  password = req.body.password;
  cpassword = req.body.cpassword;
```

Comment: In your case you are assigning the value from `req.body` to `Name` variable. and `=` is used for assigning.

Comment: But while routing when we have to get userid or whatever we use semicolon. right?

Comment: No, if we use `=` it means we are assigning value to some variable. And if we use `:`, means we are giving the reference of that variable to some key `{name: 'rupesh'}`,  here `name` is the key and `rupesh` is the value.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand, you want the `action` attribute in your sign up form. Since you already created a route `registeruser` which also has controller `user_sign_up`, just pass `registeruser` to your form as action. It should be working.

```
<form method="POST" action="/registeruser">

</form>
```

Edit:
I created a similar structure to yours, my code works well. Try to compare your code and my code and keep me updated if your issue is resolved or not.

[image]

Comment: I did the same but cannot figure out conceptually how would it find its way to the function ?

Comment: Also this is not working. When I console some random text. noting appears

Comment: If you want to understand the concept of how it finds its way to the function, it is easy, express router collects the HTTP requests. When you set action="/registeruser", form data goes to router as http request, then the controller processes your data. Accept the answer if it's properly understandable please.

Comment: sure I would. but the issue is that it's not working. its saying '/registeruser' 404 not found

Comment: Hey, I thought it was working, I'm editing my answers and I will provide screenshots.

Comment: your architecture is different. I have routes in two different places one in api/routes folder and another in server/routes folder.